# Revit Assembly Sheets No Longer Translated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I just noticed a change in behavior with the Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API.  Previously, when translating a Revit model file which contained an Assembly and the Assembly had a Sheet, the Sheet came through the translation and was available to the viewer.  Today I noticed this is no longer happening with my Forge application.  Did the API change or is this a regression in the model derivative Revit translator code?

Comment: Did you specify 2D views to be translated in your calls?

Comment: I guess that was my sort of my question... did something change in the API?  like needing to specify a new option for 2D views to be translated?  My code has not changed, but the behavior of the service must have... because a week ago the sheets were included and today they aren't.

Comment: I did just verify, I am including both 2d and 3d as views in the output format type.

Comment: Make sure you are aware of that: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/how-to-export-multiple-3d-views-for-view-and-data-api.html

Comment: Thanks Philippe.  It looks like the Forge API is now more strictly following these settings, which makes sense.  The Publish Settings under the Collaborate tab in Revit give the user full control over which views and sheets are translated once the model has been published.  This provides a lot of flexibility to users and by leveraging these settings built into Revit collaboration, it is one less thing I have to manage in my application.  I like it.